# Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ReCaptchaWebapiApi\Api\WebapiValidationConfigProviderInterface

Tags: checkout, module, shipping, webapi, interface

**I have just upgraded my magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6 and i am getting this issue on checkout shipping page and shiiping methods are not displaying.**

Error: Cannot instantiate interface Magento\ReCaptchaWebapiApi\Api\WebapiValidationConfigProviderInterface in /home/websites/bollywoo/devbwuat.wddemo.net/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php:50

Stack trace:
#0 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()

#1 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(170): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()

#2 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(276): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgument()

#3 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php(239): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->getResolvedArgument()

#4 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(34): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->resolveArgumentsInRuntime()

#5 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Dynamic/Developer.php(59): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->_resolveArguments()

#6 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Dynamic\Developer->create()

#7 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/PluginList/PluginList.php(173): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get()

#8 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(133): Magento\Framework\Interception\PluginList\PluginList->getPlugin()

#9 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()

#10 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/RequestValidator/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator\Interceptor->___callPlugins()

#11 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(108): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\RequestValidator\Interceptor->validate()

#12 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()

#13 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->___callParent()

#14 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception{closure}()

#15 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver/Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->___callPlugins()

#16 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/SynchronousRequestProcessor.php(85): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver\Interceptor->resolve()

#17 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(202): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\SynchronousRequestProcessor->process()

#18 /home/websites/hollywoo/dev/public_html/vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch()

**Please suggest any solution. I am stuck on this issue from many days.**

Comment: Clear your varnish cache. This is deep caching your all configuration.

Comment: Solved this issue by enabling the modules-  'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiApi' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiGraphQl' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiRest' => 1,
        'Magento_ReCaptchaWebapiUi' => 1,